# HTMLAgilitPack use in SSIS script task

Tags: sql-server, dll, ssis, html-agility-pack, etl

I am attempting to use the [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) in an SSIS script task. The first time it worked (or at least that what I remember). When I attempt to debug the task it invokes an error. I then reopen the script task and Visual Studio can no longer find the `htmlagilitypack` library reference. I've even included it specifically in the project. Has anyone had a similar issue and were able to solve it?

Comment: Please post the error message you reference in the question. Some more information about your setup would be nice

Comment: My guess is that you tried to add a local reference to it and have not put the DLL in the GAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the exception is thrown because the reference is not found at runtime, you have to assign this reference to the [Global Cache assembly using GACUTIL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac) or just copy the `HtmlAgilityPack.dll` file to the following directories:

**(1) .Net Framework dll directory**

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v[.net installed version]\
```

*example*

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
```

**(2) SQL server data tools dll runtime directory**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQL Server version]\DTS\Binn
```

*example*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn
```